# Correlated Subqueries with Django's ORM

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, correlated-subquery, django-filter

Is there a way to model a correlated subquery using Django's ORM?  Did I overlook this in the documentation somewhere?

I'm using Python 3.3, Django 1.7, and Django REST Framework 3.0.0.  This is all against a legacy database - Django Models are in `Managed = False` mode.

In one of my `ModelViewSets`, I'm trying to set `queryset`.  If I were writing SQL, what I need is:

```
select * from table
where dateField = (
    select max(dateField)
    from table lookup
    where lookup.varField = table.varField
)
```

I will also need to perform a .filter() on this query (adding fields to the WHERE clause in the outer query).

The `ModelViewSet` works if I give it a `RawQuerySet` (`model.objects.raw()`) with the above query, but then I can't filter using `filter_fields` in my `ModelViewSet`.

I've gotten results that are somewhat close by using `annotate`:

```
TableModel.objects.values('varField').annotate(dateField=Max('dateField')).filter(varField='aString')
```

However, I need all the columns from table, and if I just use `values()` the ORM puts every field in its `GROUP BY` clause, whereas I only need `varField` in the `GROUP BY`.

Could someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.